# Xamarin Google Maps Custom Message Popup

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am trying to place a Custom Message Box on click of Google Map Maker in Xamarin Forms. I need to use it in Cross Platform Application for both Android and iOS. Is there any reference code or any help can be provided. Would be highly thankful.

Comment: About custom Map pin, please take a look:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map-pin

Comment: Custom Map Pin is already done. The issue is Custom Message Popup when we click on that PIN.

Comment: and we need to do it in xamarin.forms.googlemaps.
your reference is from xamarin.forms.maps

Comment: About custom pin for googlemaps, you may take a look:https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps/blob/master/XFGoogleMapSample/XFGoogleMapSample/CustomPinsPage.xaml.cs